# click event not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

in chrome, no error, no warning and even no info.
it just not work.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var cbxAdmins = $("input[name^=hasAdmin][type=checkbox]");
        for (var i = 0; i < cbxAdmins.Length; i++) {

            cbxAdmins[i].click(function () {
                var checkAll = this.checked;
                var permiCheckboxes = $(this).parents("tr:first").find(':checkbox');

                if (checkAll) {
                    $(permiCheckboxes).attr('checked', true);
                }
                else {
                    $(permiCheckboxes).attr('checked', '');
                }
            });
        }


    });
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the click event? If you put an alert / trace in the first line of the cilck delegate does that not fire either?

Comment: Have you checked your css selector? what is the value of `cbxAdmins.Length`?

Comment: have you checked the value of cbxAdmins[i]?

Comment: You get that kind of thing when the element's not found by jQuery. Selector deosn't work most likely

Comment: Ain't it `length` and not `Length`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `for` loop across all the elements in the array, jQuery is smart enough to apply the click event individually. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name^=hasAdmin][type=checkbox]").click(function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

I've also cleaned up the logic a little, with thanks to Fabricio Matte.

Comment: May as well use `.prop` instead of `.attr`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté old habits die hard :)

Comment: +1, I started using jQuery on version 1.7 so I hadn't the <1.6 experience to use `.attr` for properties. `=]`

Comment: `.parents("tr:first")` could be rewritten to `.closest('tr')` I assume too. Just nitpicking on the performance, but doesn't really matter. `:P`

Comment: Also, [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) is deprecated on jQuery 1.8 because it doesn't provide the native QSA performance boost which `[type="checkbox"]` does. Ok enough from me. `=]`

Comment: Rory updated his answer. `=]` Don't worry, my updates were just for small performance nitpicks. Both codes will perform the same.